# Get ui-select value into function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, ui-select

I want to bind the ui select json data in another .form-group.

I want to get the model data in ng-click function.

my code:

```
form(novalidate='', name='bookForm')
            .col-lg-12
              .col-lg-6
                .form-group
                  label.col-md-3.control-label(for='states') Customer
            .col-lg-12(style='margin-left:135px;margin-top:-41px;')
              .col-lg-6
                .form-group
                  ui-select(ng-model='model.selected',required)
                    ui-select-match(placeholder='Pick one...') {{$select.selected.fName}}
                    ui-select-choices(repeat='person in customers | filter: $select.search track by person.fName')
                      div(ng-bind-html='person.fName | highlight: $select.search')
                      div(ng-bind-html='person.email | highlight: $select.search')
                    ui-select-no-choice
                      | Dang!  We couldn't find any choices...

              .col-lg-2
                .form-group
                  h1 {{model.selected}}
                  button.pull-right.btn.btn-primary.waves-effect.waves-light( ng-disabled='bookForm.$invalid', value='Add to list',ng-click='getdata(model.selected)')
                    i.fa.fa-plus &nbsp;
                    | New Ticket
```

I want to bind this {{$select.selected.fName}} data in another .form-group

```
h1 {{$select.selected.fName}}
```

i want to get this an a one object

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) documentation can help you here. You can add an `on-select` attribute to the directive, defining a function to call when the user selects an option. This passes the selected $item and $model to the defined function.